# Cannot find an overload for op_subtraction when subtracting datetime from datetime in powershell

Tags: datetime, runtime-error, powershell-2.0

When running the below code I receive a `cannot find an overload for op_subtraction` error, reporting that the second argument is invalid.

The faulty line is:

`if ($now - (Get-Job -Id $job.id).PSBeginTime -gt [TimeSpan]::FromMinutes($killTaskTimeMins)) {`

(changed to the below to aid debugging)

`if (($now - $when) -gt [TimeSpan]::FromMinutes($killTaskTimeMins))`

Full Code:

```
ForEach($computer in $adComputers){
    #ensure no nore than $throttle jobs run at any one time
    while (@(Get-Job | Where-Object { $_.State -eq 'Running' }).Count -gt $throttle) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $throttleSleepMS
        #in case any jobs get stuck, kill after x minutes
        $now = Get-Date
        foreach ($job in @(Get-Job -State Running)) {
            #$when = Coalesce((Get-Job -Id $job.id).PSBeginTime,$now) #had a custom function to ensure this wasn't null; but didn't help / on doing the write-host found this wasn't null anyway so removed the line
            $when = (Get-Job -Id $job.id).PSBeginTime
            write-host "now: " + $now   #seems to be a valid datetime
            write-host "when: " + $when #seems to be a valid datetime

            if (($now - $when) -gt [TimeSpan]::FromMinutes($killTaskTimeMins)) { # <-- ERROR OCCURS HERE

                Stop-Job $job
            }
        }
    }
    Start-Job -FilePath GetIEVersion.ps1 -ArgumentList $computer #here we call a custom script to grab some data
}
#more stuff here to iterate through the results of the jobs & output to csv
```

Strangely this works fine on my machine, but errors on a colleague's, so I'm guessing it's something about his environment...

Comment: try to see this: `write-host "when: " + $when.gettype()` to show the type of second argument of the subtraction.

Comment: Thanks @CB.  On mine it's DateTime; according to the docs it's Nullable<DateTime> (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.job.psbegintime(v=vs.85).aspx).  We've not tested on my colleague's as realised he was on PS2 whilst I was PS3, so are now in the process of upgrading his machine in case that's the cause...  however running my instance in V2 mode I got a `cannot call a method on a null-valued expression` error, which supports both the type & version theories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from PowerShell 2.0 to PowerShell 3.0 resolved the issue.

As remarked by @CB in the comments, it appears the `Job.PSBeginTime` data type may have changed from `Nullable<DateTime>` to `DateTime`.

PowerShell 3.0 is included in the Windows Management Framework 3.0.
Download: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34595